# Dynamically adding ImageView using pre-designed linear layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout

I am developing an app that needs to dynamically add images at specific parts of the screen. Would that be a good idea to have Linear Layouts located at the specific places prior to run the app, so that whenever a new ImageView was needed in the run time, I can dynamically add it to it's pre-designed linear layout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Use `LinearLayout` as root xml layout

2.Add `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to `ImageView`

3.Add `ImageView` to `LinearLayout`

You can try this .

```
// weight of LinearLayout
int weight = 1;
// LinearLayout you find in your xml code 
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_linearlayout);
// LinearLayout LayoutParams ,add width 、height 、weight
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, weight);
// ImageView
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
// ImageView use setImageResource
imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
// ImageView use setLayoutParams
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
// add view to LinearLayout
linearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

**Edit**

- use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

  ```
  layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
  ```
- use `LinearLayout`

  ```
  linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  ```
- use in the `LinearLayout` xml code

  ```
  android:gravity="left"
  ```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Ok, but how do you specify where the ImageView should be exactly located in the root layout. That's my biggest concern. If it was .xml I would use attributes like layout_alignBaseline:"true" . but dynamically, I had no clue how to properly do it.